# parentNode.removeChild then append back

Tags: javascript

Hi I remove a mask div using:

```
var element = document.getElementById("sal_content_mask_wrapper");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Thats all good removes a div id sal_content_mask_wrapper

Now I need to run a check if removed append a div id sal_content_mask_wrapper into parent sal_content. Below is what I have so far:

```
  var c = document.getElementById('sal_content_mask_wrapper');

  if (!c) {
      document.getElementById('YN_div').innerHTML = 'No'; /*just a test*/
      /* add div sal_content_mask_wrapper back in parent div sal_content?*/
   } else {
      document.getElementById('YN_div').innerHTML = 'Yes';
   }
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle of what the initial page looks like?

Part of the issue is that you remove 'sal_content_mask_wrapper' from within the parent node but we do not know where that element exists in a page, where the parent node has many children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I added div back like so:

function addMask() {

```
    var b = document.getElementById('sal_content_mask');

    if (!b) {

        // Get the parent node 
        var c = document.getElementById("sal_content");
        // Create a new div 
        var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.id = 'sal_content_mask';            
        // Add the new div
        c.appendChild(d);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a simple append to the parent, you can achieve it like this:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="sal_content_mask_wrapper"><span>hello world<b>!</b></span> </div>
    <div id="YN_div">Answer</div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
var element = document.getElementById("sal_content_mask_wrapper");
var par = element.parentNode;
var answer = document.getElementById('YN_div');

par.removeChild(element);

var c = document.getElementById('sal_content_mask_wrapper');

if (!c) {
  answer.innerHTML = 'No'; /*just a test*/
  par.appendChild(element)  
} else {
  answer.innerHTML = 'Yes';
}
```

But, like I mentioned, it depends how you want your html structured, as there may be more elements within the parentNode... in this case `<div id="content"...`  [Here is a fiddle to experiment.](http://jsfiddle.net/pkKJ2/)